# Exception XML-RPC class (Python)

Tags: python

Estou tentando criar uma classe em XML-RPC, mas está dando um Exception, mas não entendi o porquê. É apenas um exemplo simples:

> server.py

```
from xmlrpc.server import SimpleXMLRPCServer
import pickle

class Animal:
 def __init__(self, number_of_paws, color):
   self.number_of_paws = number_of_paws
   self.color = color

class Sheep(Animal):
 def __init__(self, color):
   Animal.__init__(self, 4, color)     

def main():
  print("This is a server!")
  server = SimpleXMLRPCServer(("localhost", 8080))
  server.register_function(Animal.__init__)
  server.register_function(Sheep.__init__)
  server.serve_forever()

if __name__ == "__main__":
  main()
```

> client.py

```
import xmlrpc.client
import time
import pickle
import server

def main():
 print("This is a client!")
 client = xmlrpc.client.ServerProxy("http://localhost:8080")
 mary = client.server.Sheep("white")
 my_pickled_mary = pickle.dumps(mary)
 dolly = pickle.loads(my_pickled_mary)
 dolly.color = "black"
 print (str.format("Dolly is {0} ", dolly.color))
 print (str.format("Mary is {0} ", mary.color))

if __name__ == "__main__":
 start = time.time()
 main()
 tempo_total = ("--- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start))
 print("Tempo Total: " + str(tempo_total))
```

O server roda normal, mas quando vou rodar o client, ocorre este seguinte erro:

> xmlrpc.client.Fault: :method "server.Sheep" is not supported'>

O que quer dizer que o método não é suportado?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O register_function do Server deve ficar como

```
  server.register_function(Animal, "Animal")
  server.register_function(Sheep, "Sheep")
```

E no Cliente altere a linha 8 para que fique como

```
  with xmlrpc.client.ServerProxy("http://localhost:8080") as client:
```

E para um exeplo mais simples de como funciona  teste apenas com

```
  mary = client.Sheep("white")
  my_pickled_mary = pickle.dumps(mary)
  print (str.format("Mary is {0} ", mary))
```

A Saida foi:

```
Mary is {'number_of_paws': 4, 'color': 'white'} 
Tempo Total: --- 0.0032961368560791016 seconds ---
```